# Update User Defined Type data in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

Hi iam unable to update the UDT data

Here is my UDT defined;

```
create type service(svcId text,status int)  -----> user Defined Type

INSERT INTO test JSON '{"id":1,"musicid":2,"service": {"svcId": "44600612","status": 1}}'
```

--> want to update svcid from previous 44600612 to 400 with remaining field status unchanged.

tried with the below in cqlsh

```
update test set service.svcid='400' where id =1;
```

got the below exception

```
SyntaxException: <ErrorMessage code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:26 no viable alternative at input '.' (update test set service[.]...)">
```

Comment: `user-defined types that include only non-collection fields can update individual field values`... check your table structure

Comment: can you explain it ,as my UDT dont have any map set or list

Comment: partial update is possible in cassandra 3...

Comment: yes @undefined_variable ,docs says that but while executing its giving error ? Any idea about this